# First-differences vs. pooled OLS

Tags: regression, econometrics, panel-data, group-differences, pooling

Two-period panel regression model:

- $Y_{it}=\beta_0\delta_{t2} + \beta_1X_{it} +\alpha_i + \epsilon_{it}$

where

- $t=1, 2$
- $i=1,...,n$ indexes the cross sectional units drawn via random sampling.
- $\alpha_i$ is an individual-specific unobserved effect.
- $\delta_i=1$ if $t=2$; $0$ if $t=1$

In other words:

- $Y_{i1}=\beta_1X_{i1} +\alpha_i + \epsilon_{i1}$
- $Y_{i2}=\beta_0 + \beta_1X_{i2} +\alpha_i + \epsilon_{i2}$

Now for the first-difference estimator $\hat{\beta_1}^{FD}$ to be consistent, one must assume strict exogeneity :

- $E[\epsilon_{it}|X_{i2}, X_{i1}]=0$ for $t=1, 2$

For the pooled OLS estimator $\hat{\beta_1}^{POLS}$ to be consistent, one must assume weak exogeneity:

- $E[u_{it}|X_{it}]=0$ where $u_{it}=\alpha_i + \epsilon_{it}$

I know that $\hat{\beta_1}^{POLS}$ will be less efficient than $\hat{\beta_1}^{FD}$ because $u_{it}=\alpha_i + \epsilon_{it}$ is serially correlated, but **is it necessarily the case that first-difference estimators will always be superior to pooled OLS estimators?**

Surely the assumption of strict exogeneity in the first-differences case rules out the possibility that $X$ might have a persistent effect on $Y$ thereby biasing $\hat{\beta_1}^{FD}$?

In other words, although the weak exogeneity assumption makes $\hat{\beta_1}^{POLS}$ inefficient might it be the case that the strict exogeneity assumption biases $\hat{\beta_1}^{FD}$? **There is a trade-off between strict and weak exogeneity.**